# Switching language and the subsequent input of capital letters

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, input-language

Previously, using Ubuntu 16, I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch the language,  let go of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, left my finger on the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button, and was then able to enter a capital letter.

Now, in Ubuntu 18.04, after using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, lower-case letters continue to be entered, even though the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is being pressed.  I have to press it again to enter a capital letter.

I find this terribly inconvenient and very uncomfortable.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. It's very uncomfortable. I filed a bug report on bugtracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1797389. I found a solution to this problem. The problem was with Xorg.

1. Add this repository: ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
   ```
2. Upgrade the system.

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
   ```
3. Reboot.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```